# API returns data, but Redux doesn't change the state

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, reactjs

I am using Spring Boot for the API, I have a method which returns all of the articles from the database. It is a GET method mapped on /api/articles. (Tested with Postman, it works as it should)

Also, while inspecting with the Redux extension I can see that the state for the articles only contains the placeholder article.

**No errors in the console.**.
Also important, the case GET_ARTICLES is successfully called (resp.data contains all the articles).

Now on the front-end, I am using Redux to store the articles. Here is how my Reducer looks:

```
import { GET_ARTICLES } from "../actions/types";
import repo from "../repository/axiosRepository";
const InitialState = {
  articles: [
    {
      title: "Lord of the rings",
      author: "JR Talkins",
      content: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      id: 1
    }
  ]
};

export default function(state = InitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ARTICLES:
      repo.fetchArticles().then(resp => {
        return {
          articles: resp.data
        };
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And this is my component where I would like to display the articles:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Article from '../article/Article';
import articleService from '../../repository/axiosRepository';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems } from '../../actions/articleActions';

class HomePage extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getItems();
    }

    render() {
        let { articles } = this.props.articles;

        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-9">
                {articles && articles.map(article => <Article key={article.id} article={article}/>)}
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                widgets
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  articles: state.articles
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getItems})(HomePage);
```

I don't understand why returning the object with the resp.data doesn't change the state.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue for this is in your reducer.
`repo.fetchArticles()` is an async function, it should be called in your action creator like so:

```
function getItems() {
  repo.fetchArticles().then(resp => {
     return {
       type: GET_ARTICLES
       payload: resp.data
     };
   });
}
```

Fetch the data in your action creator, and call the reducer with already fetched data.

```
case GET_ARTICLES:
      return { articles: action.payload };
```